# Extract information from HTML and add it to data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have modified an initial code I had written scraping all the page with Pandas. I bellieve its easier, especially because it will hopefully help me with procesing the data with PowerBI. I now extract all the tables however I'm having trouble adding certain information.

`import pandas as pd df = pd.read_html('https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2223/futbol-11/divisio-honor-cadet/grup-1/hc/barcelona-fc-a/hc/damm-cf-a')[4] print(df.head())`

Targetes Targetes.1  Targetes.2
0  5  TORRENTS SALVAT, JOFRE        36'         NaN

On the column Targetes.2 I would like to add the value yellow or red based on the booking type. To do so in the old code I was looking for the class 'groga-s' or 'vermella-s' but with this code I'm having trouble.

I have tried to add the code:

`df.loc[df['class'] == 'groga-s', 2] = 'groga'`

But this returns me an error.

Can anyone help me know how to do it.